# Python Windows service autostarts too early

Tags: python, windows-services

I am running a Python script as a Windows service, but it seems to be failing whenever I set it to auto-start. I believe this may be because the service uses network resources that are not yet mounted when the service starts. Is there a way I can get it to wait until startup is complete before running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Configure your Windows Service so that [it has the `Workstation` Service as a dependency](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888).

This means Windows won't attempt to start your service until the appropriate resources are available.

Comment: I should really read more about Windows internals, I'm always surprised when I find out that things like this exist :-\

Answer (score 2):

Add in script wait for the resources who script must use is in good standing, or rewrite script to better design like not exit if dont have connection; wait 1s and try again if connection failed.

Comment: You're right, of course. I think I was just being lazy and not wanting to debug what's actually going wrong. But of course, I will!